# What internal operation does Mongoose returning object do?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a story which may be a little tedious.But I was really confused about this problem.Here it is:
I was trying to change the value of the article object which was returned by Mongoose static Model method in my service layer.Here is what the object looks like:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ddc7ce28251373510d4e49b"),
    "tag" : [
        "Error handling",
        "async/await"
    ],
    "title" : "title",
    "content" : "This is an article",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-11-26T09:16:18.177+08:00"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-11-26T10:04:41.636+08:00"),
    "view" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ddc7cee8251373510d4e49c"),
            "email" : "123",
            "viewAt" : ISODate("2019-11-26T09:16:30.733+08:00")
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ddcdcefa4ac2a9f54228a42"),
            "email" : "123",
            "viewAt" : ISODate("2019-11-26T16:06:07.310+08:00")
        },

    ],
    "thumbUp" : [
        {
            "email" : "123",
            "thumbedAt" : ISODate("2019-11-26T16:46:17.870+08:00")
        }
    ],
    "comment" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ddcea9efa1afbbe082cc051"),
            "userId" : "5d836cacc845921e1034f1da",
            "text" : "fff",
            "commentAt" : ISODate("2019-11-26T17:04:30.166+08:00")
        },
    ],
    "__v" : 0
},
```

Then I used userIds inside the comment array to do some other database query(like fetching username) and combined fetched data with the original comment data to form a new comment array. Here what a new comment array looks like:

```js
{
    _id: 5ddcea9efa1afbbe082cc051,
    userId: '5d836cacc845921e1034f1da',
    text: 'This is quite useful!',
    commentAt: 2019-11-27T05:59:21.164Z,
    username: 'Sherr_Y',
    hasAvatar: true
}
```

Then here comes the problem: When I tried to replace the original comment with the new one.I found nothing changed.Here's what I have tried:

```js
_data.comment = newCommentArray;
// or
Object.assign(_data, { comment: newCommentArray });
```

Finally I found that _data is not a object which only contains the data.Here's what it really looks like:

```js
{
  '$__': InternalCache {
    strictMode: true,
    selected: {},
    shardval: undefined,
    saveError: undefined,
    validationError: undefined,
    adhocPaths: undefined,
    removing: undefined,
    inserting: undefined,
    saving: undefined,
    version: undefined,
    getters: {},
    _id: 5ddc7ce28251373510d4e49b,
    populate: undefined,
    populated: undefined,
    wasPopulated: false,
    scope: undefined,
    activePaths: StateMachine {
      paths: [Object],
      states: [Object],
      stateNames: [Array]
    },
    pathsToScopes: {},
    cachedRequired: {},
    session: undefined,
    '$setCalled': Set {},
    ownerDocument: undefined,
    fullPath: undefined,
    emitter: EventEmitter {
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
      _eventsCount: 0,
      _maxListeners: 0
    },
    '$options': { skipId: true, isNew: false, willInit: true }
  },
  isNew: false,
  errors: undefined,
  _doc: {
    tag: ["Error handling","async/await"],
    _id: 5ddc7ce28251373510d4e49b,
    title: 'title',
    content: 'This is an article',
    createdAt: 2019-11-26T01:16:18.177Z,
    updatedAt: 2019-11-26T02:04:41.636Z,
    view: [
      [Object], [Object]
    ],
    thumbUp: [ [Object] ],
    comment: [ [Object] ],
    __v: 0
  },
  '$locals': {},
  '$init': true
}
```

Obviously, the value of _doc is just what we exactly need.So I dealt it with `const res = Object.assign({ ..._data._doc }, { comment });` Now it works.Even though I can continue my work,I still wonder what magic does the mongoose returning object have.Here I have two main questions:

- It only shows the data we need(_doc) when I try below:

  ```js
  console.log(_data);

  // Only output what inside _doc
  ```

  But it output the entire object when I try below:

  ```js
  console.log({ ...data });

  // Output the entire object
  ```

  Why `data` and `{ ...data }` have different behaviors in console.log.Is it about the javascript internal rules or is it set by Mongoose.And how?
- When I use `return _data` but not `return { ..._data }` to return it from sevice to controller.I still can get the entire object by `console.log({ ...data })` in controller layer.But when I use `res.json(_data)` to return it to front-end.No matter what I did, I can only get the data inside _doc.Seems like `res.json(_data)` only returns what inside _doc.But how did this finished?

Answer (score 0):

If you created mongoose query to find something inside your database as an answer you will not receive just an Object it will be a **mongoose Query Object** which contains a lot of useful staff which you can call on returned **mongoose Query Object**. Here you can find more about this Query Object and Query Object methods: [Monoose Query Object](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#Query).

To update some properties of your **mongoose query object** you can use this method:

`queryObject.findOneAndUpdate(conditions, update)`

I think it will fit perfectly

Comment: So this **mongoose Query Object** can not only return the data I need but can also  execute some extra method provided by Mongoose.That sounds really make sense.I've just viewed the **mongoose Query Object** in Mongoose document.Seems like it only shows what methods this object has but doesn't give me enough information to answer my questions on its weird behaviors.Still,thank you very much,dude.:D